# Forcemerge function in Indexwriter class

Tags: search, jakarta-ee, solr, lucene, search-engine

I wanted to know about a function in Solr3.5.0 in the IndexWriter class. can anyone let me know what exactly the forceMerge() function does. Does it optimize the segments?

Thanks,

Jeyaprakash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `forceMerge` is the successor of `optimize`. There are two main reasons for this renaming:

- Lucene multi-segment performance has increased a lot over the last years,
- Giving a less cool name to this method will prevent users from thinking that this method does some kind of magic and that any index is sub-optimal until this method has been called.

You can read more about this renaming at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3454

Comment: Good answer, I would add just one thing: don't use optimize, even if it's now called forceMerge! :) Also, this [article](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3A-optimize-is-bad-for-you) might be interesting.