# Lucene migration from 3.x to 4.1.0 and index optimisation

Tags: java, migration, lucene

I have migrated from lucene 3.x to 4.1.0. After creating new index I realise there is much more files in the index directory. lucene 3 uses IndexWriter.optimize() to collapse files.
The [succesor in v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483083/forcemerge-function-in-indexwriter-class) is [IndexWriter.forceMerge(int maxNumSegments)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#forceMerge%28int%29). I have tried forceMerge with different values for maxNumSegments and I get always the same index files. I expect the files to be merge together into one, or at least less, index files. Am I wrong? Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for Lucene's compound file format which stores all logical index files in a single actual file. See [MergePolicy.setUseCompoundFile(true)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TieredMergePolicy.html#setUseCompoundFile%28boolean%29).

Comment: I am looking for that but You ment probably. TieredMergePolicy.setUseComoundFile(boolean) which is default TRUE. So it does not make any difference for me. Any other idea?

Comment: By default, only segments which are less than 10% of the size of the index use the CFS format. You can set NOCFSRatio=1.0 to have all files in CFS http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TieredMergePolicy.html#setNoCFSRatio(double)

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it works. Thanks. Now is the question: Is it better to use multi-file index or set the ration to for example 1.0 and has all in *.cfs file?

Comment: The problem of CFS is that it is a little slower, so I think the default configuration is good: small segments (less than 10% of the index size) are kept into CFS files to keep the number of open files low, and large segments don't use CFS for optimal speed.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from ideological (less files better than more), are there any practical reasons why do you need less files? Providing the overall number of bytes for given index is roughly the same, what's the difference?

The reason why optimization was removed because it was inefficient: it would kill search performance, result load spikes, etc. Performance over searching over multiple segments has improved and the need to `.optimize()`  is no longer justifiable. Lucene now uses `TieredMergePolicy` instead which [nicely balances the load](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html) and solves this problem from a different angle.